# allocate on the fly vectors into fortran from python using f2py

Tags: python, fortran, f2py

I have the following start of a subroutine called by python:

Called from python using: `libomp.cic(pos,mpart,boxsize,dim,npart)`

```
subroutine cic(pos,mpart,boxsize,dim,npart,mesh)
use omp_lib
implicit none 
real*8 mpart
!f2py intent(in) :: mpart
real*8 boxsize
!f2py intent(in) :: boxsize
integer dim
!f2py intent(in) :: dim
integer*8 npart
!f2py intent(in) :: npart
real*8, dimension(0:dim-1,0:dim-1,0:dim-1) :: mesh
!f2py intent(out) :: mesh
real*8, dimension(npart,3) :: pos
!f2py intent(in) :: pos
```

Error when running python script:

```
error: (shape(pos,0)==npart) failed for 1st keyword npart: cic:npart=47099622
WARNING: Failure executing file: <test.py>
```

For some reason it works when I set `npart` as an integer but it can't receive `npart` from python and create the array `pos` on the fly. It works for `mesh` using `dim` but not `pos`, why? Does it have something to do with the ordering in which they are called?

Comment: Comment: why do you not specify the intent directly in Fortran?

Comment: I can do that... either way should work. I just checked - same error.

Comment: Can you post some relevant part of the test script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pos` is declared to be `intent(in)` which means that it is supposed to be allocated when you enter the routine.  Note that this is completely different than using an automatic array in fortran since `pos` is a dummy argument.  The problem is that since `pos` is `intent(in)`, `f2py` is checking it's declared dimensions with the dimensions that you're passing in (`mpart`) because `npart` is also supposed to be `intent(in)`.  Since they don't match, you're getting an error.

In other words, you have 2 `intent(in)` variables and the values that you're passing in for them are incompatible.  The actual solution really depends on what the subroutine is supposed to be doing, and what the intent of the dummy arguments actually should be.

If `pos` is really `intent(in)`, then you could in principle change `npart` to `intent(hide)` in which case, numpy will pass the `npart` to your subroutine based on the allocated dimensions of `pos`. e.g., I believe it will be called as:

```
libomp.cic(pos,mpart,boxsize,dim)
```

Comment: You are right, it's a dummy argument. Don't know, how could I not notice this.

Comment: Thanks. pos is a Nx3 vector which changes shape in python. I want to feed this vector into fortran but (if I understand correctly), Fortran must already know what length pos is when it comes from python. The length changes each time so I have to allocate a Nx3 array each time pos is sent to cic. Is there a way for Fortran to receive an arbitrary sized Nx3 matrix without having to send npart (N) as well?

Comment: @Griff -- That's what I'm talking about with the `intent(hide)`.  This way, no matter what Nx3 matrix you pass in, your subroutine will be passed `N` as `npart`.